# How to get count of columns whose value greater than 40 from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get column count whose value greater than 40

**example :**

```
id col_1 col_2 col_3

1   20     60  80
```

The output like this `count=2`

**query:**

```
select count(columns) from table where id =1 and col_values >40;
```

How to write query to get this please help me to write query.

Comment: I have the feeling this is a poorly designed schema

Comment: `mySQL` or `Oracle` please?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Premise:

Your database is not normlized! Please, normalize it.

### Solution:

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN col1 >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END +
    CASE
        WHEN col2 >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END +
    CASE
        WHEN col3 >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END)
FROM yourtable
```

With this query you summarize all columns and you'll get only sum trasversal by rows.

So, if you have this result set

```
id col_1 col_2 col_3

1   20     60  80
2   44     22  20
```

You'll get 3 (two from row with id 1 and 1 for row with id 2)

**EDIT**

If you want get this information only for one row you can integrate you query with `id = value` (as in your question) so the query becomes:

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN col1 >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END +
    CASE
        WHEN col2 >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END +
    CASE
        WHEN col3 >= 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0
    END)
FROM yourtable
WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: The question title is "count OF COLUMNS" - what you provided is a count of individual values. See the request for clarification I put in a Comment to the OP's question.

Comment: I suppose the tile must be re-write, because in the body of question our friend wants a total number (he has accepted my answer)

Comment: Actually I looked at the question again and the OP has a WHERE condition. If id is primary key, then he is, in fact, looking at only one row at a time. You may want to edit your answer to reflect that; he wasn't looking to count all values across the entire table, but only across one row.